# Point features disappear when adding new data

Tags: point, features

Recently while adding features to a point layer i noticed that once i had saved my edits the already existing points disappeared. Although not visable on the map all of them and their data were still in the attribute table. Any guesses on how to make all of the points viewable again?

Thanks,

L

Comment: What GIS program do you use?