# Add features to point layer in QGIS 2.12

Tags: point, editing, qgis-2.12

I work with QGIS 2.12 and i try to edit point layer by adding it more point features with "add feature" button. Here my point layer:

[image] 
[image]

after i add the features (features num. 58-62) i save editing. The problem is that i can see the added features in the attribute table:

[image]

but in the map they disappear and i can't see them

I red [Point features disappear when adding new data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18252/point-features-disappear-when-adding-new-data?rq=1) but in my situation the features can be seen when i in edit mode.

Comment: [Your question title should be a summary of what is in your question body.](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115). Please try to always mention the GIS software and version that you are using in your question body.

Comment: Which data provider / file format / database are you using? What happens if you click on the "zoom to selected" button in the attribute table with on of the affected rows selected?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following to see if the problem still exist:

1- When you add point to the map, keep the point selected and open the attribute table

2- Update the x-coordinate field with `$x` and y-coordinate field with `$y`, so that you will get the x and y coordinates of the newly added points.

3- Save the attribute table.

4-Repeat the above process after each point added.

I know it is not a perfect solution, but in this case you can confirm whether the points still exist in the map view as well as the attribute table or not.